# Distinction of Dirac monopole and Polyakov-'t Hooft monopole

Tags: quantum-field-theory, magnetic-monopoles, solitons, dirac-monopole, dirac-string

Can anybody explain the physical difference between Dirac monopole and Polyakov monopole?

First, let me write down what I know briefly.

Dirac monopole

1. It comes from the symmetry of Maxwell equation. By assuming that magnetic field for a point source magnetic charge $g$.

\begin{align}
B(r,t) = \frac{g}{4\pi r^2} \frac{\vec{r}}{r}
\end{align}
Since the divergence of $B$ gives non-vanishing value due to delta function $\nabla \cdot \nabla(\frac{1}{r})=\delta(r)$. Thus we introduce the so-called Dirac String, ($i.e$, add some solenoid field)

2. Dirac string is non-obeservable due to Dirac's charge quantization

---

Polyakov-'t Hooft  monopole.

1. It comes from soliton Dynamics. $i.e$ $SO(3)$ model
2. We can compute the mass (Energy)
3. For large distance Polyakov-'t Hooft  monopole behaves like Dirac monopole

---

You can comment anything including above things.
This question arise from the comment of my previous question [[Compact QED and Non-compact QED - Polyakov textbook](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202626/) ] by Stephen Powell

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The Dirac monopole is a solution for the pure gauge theory, the Polyakov-'t Hooft monopole arises in the presence of a Higgs-like symmetry breaking. So they aren't the same because they aren't solutions for the same theory. What *exactly* is your question about that? (Also, I don't think the "Polyakov" monopole the answer by StephenPowell mentions are the "Polyakov-'t Hooft monopoles" one usually speaks of in the continuum.)

Comment: @ACuriousMind, Oh... Polyakov monopole and Polyakov-'t Hooft monopoles are different?...Maybe i will modify the question after finding some proper references.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, What i found on the google, was [note.pdf](http://www.th.physik.uni-bonn.de/nilles/exercises/DreesNillesSeminar06/DNSeminar06_Monopoles.pdf) which cover the dirac monopole and Polyakov-'tHooft monopole

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Can you recommend some materials dealing with Polyakov monopole and Polyakov-'t Hooft monopole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A (generalized) ['t Hooft-Polyakov monopole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'t_Hooft%E2%80%93Polyakov_monopole) and
2. a [Dirac monopole with a Dirac string attached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string)

are two types of [magnetic monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), which differ in several ways, as OP and user ACuriousMind correctly state.

1. On one hand, a (generalized) 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole is a regular, soliton-like, finite-energy solution to the classical Euler-Lagrange field equations of some [GUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Unified_Theory) (with an action principle that extends the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)). Its existence is unavoidable if a certain topological condition is satisfied in the GUT.
2. On the other hand, while Dirac monopoles were mostly conceived by Dirac as a theoretical laboratory to study charge quantization, the modern interpretation is that a Dirac monopole is an effective description far away from the monopole that fails near the finite core region of the monopole. Moreover a Dirac monopole requires a non-standard action principle, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59874/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

For further differences and details, see Ref. 1 and the linked Wikipedia pages.

References:

1. F.A. Bais, *To be or not to be? Magnetic monopoles in non-abelian gauge theories,* [arXiv:hep-th/0407197](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407197). (Hat tip: [Hunter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65782/2451).)

Comment: Thanks for kind answer. Can you give me some example(or comment) of topological condition related with 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole?